подключение к бд на сервере через phpmyadamin или adminer
Арендовал облачный сервер, развернул на нем бд, подскажите пожалуйста как я могу подключиться к этой бд через phpmyadmin или adminer.
пробовал устанавливать Phpmyadmin по гайдам. все сделал по гайду, но при заходе по адресу ip_adress/phpmyadmin ничего не открывается
подскажите пожалуйста, что делать

https://selectel.ru/blog/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04/ вот гайд

В phpmyadmin можно выполнить любой SQL запрос. Для этого в меню таблицы или базы данных перейдите на вкладку SQL.
Сразу же тут вы найдете различные шаблоны для запросов.
Или можете ввести нужный запрос сами, вручную. Для выполнения запроса нажмите "Вперед". Перед вами откроется результат запроса, если были получены какие-либо поля, то они будут выведены, если же нет, то просто будет выведено сообщение о том что все прошло успешно.
